# Parse parameters of a function in a string

Tags: python

I'm really just a beginner at the code so I don't know if I'm asking a silly question, and I might even misuse some terms.

my problem is that i have in python a string, which contains a text that could be understood as a function, and i would like to extract his parameters in a list.

example of a string:

```py
line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", delay=6)"""
```

I'd like to have as a result of processing that string something like that:

```py
["boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", "delay=6"]
```

I don't know if I'm making myself clear

I'm looking for something like:

```py
line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", delay=6)"""

def function(x)
    # magic with x
    return list() # a list type result not actualy a list() xD

function(line)
```

```
>> ["boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", "delay=6)"]
```

thank you very much in advance

Comment: just use string `split(",")`

Comment: you could try venturing into the world of regex. There are plenty of online tools that can help you visualize how it works, such as [this one](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I forgot to add that I don't use a .split(',') because a string could contain commas, for example:
 ( , "Search for the compass, and stuffs", )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using `ast` module. It has`ast.NodeVisitor` which is a base class that walks the abstract syntax tree and calls a visitor function for every node found.

```
>>> line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", delay=6)"""
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse(line)
>>> args = []
>>>
>>> class VisitCall(ast.NodeVisitor):
...     def visit_Call(self, node):
...         for i in node.args + node.keywords:
...             if isinstance(i, ast.Constant):
...                 args.append(i.value)
...             if isinstance(i, ast.keyword):
...                 args.append(f"{i.arg}={i.value.value}")
...
>>> visitor = VisitCall()
>>> visitor.visit(tree)
>>> print(args)
['boatsmith search', 'Search for the holder of the golden compass', 'delay=6']
```

You can handle different conditions within the `visit_Call` method.

Comment: Thanks friend, I could not run your script as such because it gave me errors, but I replaced the pair of "if" by one that gave me the value of the strings which is what I needed most, thank you very much. | if isinstance(i, ast.Str):args.append(i.s)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

re.search('\((.*)\)', line.replace('"', '')).group(1).split(', ')
```

output:

```
['boatsmith search', 'Search for the holder of the golden compass', 'delay=6']
```

---

> the string could be written with double quotes or with single quotes

in this case you could use:

```
line = """State("boatsmith search", 'Search for the holder of the golden compass', delay=6)"""

[e.strip('"\'') for e in re.search('\((.*)\)', line).group(1).split(', ')]
```

output:

```
['boatsmith search', 'Search for the holder of the golden compass', 'delay=6']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", delay=6)"""

def function(x)
    start = x.find("(") + len("(")
    end = x.find(")")
    substring = x[start:end]
    print(substring.replace('"', '').split(','))
```

Comment: I think that `end = x.rfind(")")` is more safe, since argument can have parenthesis.

Comment: this page is a bit confusing, I can't find how to edit my own question xD
Thanks for the answer but actually I have to mention that one of the parameters could contain commas, so I didn't use a split(','), also the string could be written with double quotes or with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the holder of the golden compass", delay=6)"""

print(re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"|(\w+=\w+)', line))
```

**Output:**

```
[('boatsmith search', ''), ('Search for the holder of the golden compass', ''), ('', 'delay=6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using regular expressions. The solution is resistant to commas in strings, e. g. `"Search for the compass, and stuffs"` and string parameters with the name before, e. g. `delay="huge"`.

```
import re

def function(line):
    re_result = re.findall(r'\w+\=\w|\w+\="[^"]+"|"[^"]+"', line)
    result = [item.replace('"', '') if '=' not in item else item for item in re_result]
    return result
```

Testing line with the result looks like this:

```
>>> test_line = """State("boatsmith search", "Search for the compass, and stuff", delay=5, delay_2="big")"""
>>> function(test_line)
['boatsmith search', 'Search for the compass, and stuff', 'delay=5', 'delay_2="big"']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.